# What's the coding for displaying many locations in google map using latitude and longitude value

Tags: google-maps

I used this code but its not working.

```
function initialize() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(10.35,79.4167), 13);
    var marker = new GMarker(new GLatLng(10.35,79.4167));
     map.setCenter(new GLatLng(8.7167,77.483), 14);
    var marker = new GMarker(new GLatLng(8.7167,77.483));
     map.setCenter(new GLatLng(21.83,78.75), 15);
    var marker = new GMarker(new GLatLng(21.83,78.75));
     map.addOverlay(marker);

    map.setUIToDefault();
  }
}
```

Comment: You had tagged this question with the google-maps-api-v3 tag. I moved it into the more general google-maps tag because it is more likely to get attention there.  Also, the code you are using is from version two of the API.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will only add the last marker. You are only calling *addOverlay* once at the end (so only the last marker will be added to the map).

You also call *setCenter* multiple times, so only the last setCenter will be applied to the map.  *setCenter* just sets the visible area on the Google Map.

You are using Google Maps v2 in your code, I suggest you check out the more current [v3 API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/).  If you are starting a new project, you may as well use the latest stuff.

If you have some other reason for using the v2 API, there is a [range of good samples](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/examples/index.html) to get you started.